# RESTful CRUD functions which handle multiple actions?

Tags: laravel, rest, vuex, api-design

I'm currently developing an app in Laravel. While trying to adhere to REST API guidelines I've come across a scenario that I'm not sure how to handle RESTfully.

I have a Lease resource that handles multiple actions:

```
Route::get('/lease/create', 'API\LeaseController@create');
Route::get('/lease/{leaseId}', 'API\LeaseController@show');
Route::post('/lease', 'API\LeaseController@store');
Route::patch('/lease/{leaseId}', 'API\LeaseController@update');
Route::delete('/lease/{leaseId}', 'API\LeaseController@destroy');
```

So far these are a 1:1 between the URI and the controller actions. Now I have additional operations that I need to perform on a Lease and this is where I'm not sure what the best way to handle this is.

1) A Lease can be renewed (clone existing lease with new start and end dates).

2) A Lease can be ended (status changed to Inactive, end date updated).

When I think about doing this RESTfully I look at these two additional operations as a post and a patch to existing endpoints (both would map to the store and update method on the controller and could use the existing URIs.

Should I continue to think about it that way and map them both to existing endpoints? My concern with that is how would I handle different responses? For example if after a renew operation completes I want to pass a message saying "This lease has been successfully renewed.", how would I differentiate between a renew operation and a regular store operation since they both hit the same end point?

Or should I create two new URI's, something like:

```
Route::patch('/lease/{leaseId}/end', 'API\LeaseController@updateLeaseEnd');
Route::post('/lease/{leaseId}/renew', 'API\LeaseController@storeLeaseRenew');
```

And control logic in two separate functions even though it would be somewhat redundant since they really are just additional stores and updates?

Comment: I would go with additional route that has different handler. Because you will have a fully testable application for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to fit a RPC style API into a RESTful style API, which is possible, but can be confusing. You could do like you were saying with using the PATCH method, but now you have an overloaded method that should only do a partial update, but now it *might* execute an action on the resource. That would be confusing.

One way I've seen this done is by using what is called a verb (not to be confused by the "HTTP Verb") in the URI. This is essentially what you were stating as your last option in the question.

Structure

```
https://api.domain.com/namespace/resource/_verb
https://api.domain.com/namespace/resource/{id}/_verb
```

Example

```
https://api.domain.com/namespace/lease/{id}/_end
https://api.domain.com/namespace/lease/{id}/_renew
```

The underscore is there to signify that this is not a resource, but rather an execution call.

Another option would be to separate your REST API from your RPC API. You could use the traditional SOAP web service or go with the new [gRPC](https://grpc.io/), by Google.